# Pentaho Reporting: Columns getting restricted in Pentaho reports

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have too many columns (more than 15) to be shown in the reports but the pentaho report designer is restricting the same. I can only show 5-6 columns. How to expand the area size of the report columns?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the size type,example A4 type or something and also you can modify the height and weight of the component so that you can accommodate more columns.

Comment: I confirm. Under the main `menu/file`, open the `Page Setup`, and in there, select a `Page Size` of `Standard A0`.